# What is the difference between these two C declarations

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I declared and initialized a 2x2 array as follows:

```
int arr[2][2] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Then, a pointer to integer:

```
int *p1;
```

Initialize the pointer as:

```
p1 = arr[0];    //p1 points to {1, 2}
```

Now I can print elements using `p1` as `*p1`

Now, when I declare:

```
int (*ptr)[2][2];
ptr = &arr;
```

To print the elements, now I have to use:

```
printf("%d\n", *(**(ptr)+1));
```

What is the difference between these two declarations?

Comment: In what context are you attempting to use `ptr`?  A more complete example would be helpful.

Comment: If this is truly C I think you're going to need to use malloc in your second example.

Comment: @Ian, not in this case, since I have already initialized the matrix, and `ptr` is being made to point to it.

Comment: @AdityaMedhe I suppose you know the difference between int arr[2][2] = {1,2,3,4}; and  int arr[2][2] = {{1,2} , {3,4}}?

Comment: @Michi No, hitherto I used to think that they are equal, the braces to indicate the rows are optional. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Nothing is wrong , just checking :). Any way, at some point, after coding like 5000 lines, if there is a missing bracket .....well you will learn to use them. :)

Comment: My point is (as advice ) never ignore things just because they are optional.

Comment: Even I agree with that, and follow it regularly. Posted in this way here for the sake of brevity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int (*ptr)[2][2];` is a pointer to a 2x2 matrix, not a pointer to an `int`. Since each dimension of a matrix behaves somewhat like a pointer, that is why you need extra dereferencing in the `printf`.

Comment: Agreed, but my point is, can I just use first method because it is so simpler and performs similarly as the second one? Is there any real need for `(*ptr)[2][2]`?

Comment: If you know what you are doing, you can pretty much use the one you like better. C is very flexible. But if are starting, I would advise sticking to the simples solution.

Comment: @AdityaMedhe The first method is definitely preferable.  It's more concise than the second and easier to understand.

Comment: BTW, if you want to print the first row of the matrix with the second form, I would prefer using `(*ptr)[0]`. This should be equivalent to using the pointer in your first example.

Comment: Thank you for your help, cenouro, dbush.